# Laravel autoloading classes within custom folders

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, psr-4

I have a project and need to make it so I no longer have to run composer dump-autoload when creating new classes

The project has custom folders like this
`App\Features`
`App\Concerns`

I've gone into composer.json, and added the last entry to the following:

```
"classmap": [
  "database/seeds",
  "database/factories",
  "app/Features"
],
```

Then I run the following commands

`php artisan clear-compiled`
`composer dump-autoload`
`php artisan optimize`

Then I went ahead and created a new class within Features called TestFeature.php, with a static function that simply prints out that it worked

I tried executing this without composer dump-autoload, but it throws an error saying the class cannot be found.

What is the best approach to autoload classes within custom folders?

Thanks

Comment: you should dump them to composer autoload as you have done. there is no purpose to put them within classmap as i know if you use composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are using the incorrect key `classmap` for this. you should be using `psr-4`.

For example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Features\\": "app/Features/"
    },
    "classmap": [ ... ]
},
```

Then run `composer dump-auto`.

P.S. putting the `Features` folder under `app` folder is a little strange; as `app` is already mapped to `App`.